# Combining Multidimensional Array Values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [description] => UPS Ground
                    [delivery-time] => 1-5 business days
                    [shipping-amount] => 1299
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [description] => UPS 3 Day Select
                    [delivery-time] => 3 business days
                    [shipping-amount] => 2459
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [description] => UPS 2nd Day Air
                    [delivery-time] => 2 business days
                    [shipping-amount] => 3239
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [description] => UPS Ground
                    [delivery-time] => 1-5 business days
                    [shipping-amount] => 864
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [description] => UPS 3 Day Select
                    [delivery-time] => 3 business days
                    [shipping-amount] => 1109
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [description] => UPS 2nd Day Air
                    [delivery-time] => 2 business days
                    [shipping-amount] => 1633
                )
             [3] => Array
                (
                    [description] => UPS Overnight
                    [delivery-time] => 1 business day
                    [shipping-amount] => 3528
                )

        )

)
```

I'm trying to achieve 3 things:

1. Add the values of the `shipping-amount` where the `description` is the same across dimensions
2. Drop the `array` if it contains a `description` which doesn't exist in every other dimension
3. Drop a dimension once the shipping-amounts are combined

There may be several first-level arrays (not just 2 as shown here), but this is as deep as the dimensions will go. I'm looking for the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [description] => UPS Ground
            [delivery-time] => 1-5 business days
            [shipping-amount] => 2163
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [description] => UPS 3 Day Select
            [delivery-time] => 3 business days
            [shipping-amount] => 3568
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [description] => UPS 2nd Day Air
            [delivery-time] => 2 business days
            [shipping-amount] => 4872
        )
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This really sounds too much like "please write code for me" instead of a description of a particular problem. What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: What have I tried? I've tried reading the PHP manual through dozens of amazingly ridiculous array functions to figure out which are appropriate for this scenario. I figure it may be some combination of a `foreach`, `array_merge`, `array_map`, `key()` but I don't know which order or functions make the most sense. I've had some great help for problems that challenge me here before, so I figured I'd ask again instead of wasting time putzing around.

Comment: Wasting time putzing around is often the one true way to learn to do it yourself though. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
$final=array(); // the final array
$count=array(); // keeps track of instances of each description
$loops=count($array);
for($a=0;$a<$loops;$a++){
    foreach($array[$a] as $s){ //loop through child arrays
        if($count[$s['description']]>0){ //check if description exists in $count
            foreach($final as $k=>$v){ //add sums to the final if it does exist
                if($final[$k]['description']==$s['description']){$final[$k]['shipping-amount']+=$s['shipping-amount'];}
            }
        }else{ //if it doesn't exist in the count array, add it to the final array
            $final[]=$s;
        }
        $count[$s['description']]++;//update the count array
    }
}
//Unset singletons, using the count array
foreach($count as $k=>$v){
    if($v==1){
        foreach($final as $key=>$val){
            if($final[$key]['description']==$k){unset($final[$key]);}
        }
    }
}
print_r($final);
```

I have been stuck on an issue for the past 2 days and feel you, so I hope this helps.

Comment: If it doesn't work, it's at least something you could tweak and get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Even if it doesn't work, I'm not looking for a copy/paste. Just something to get me started in the right direction. Cheers to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write code because I agree with **deceze**.

Nonetheless, my recommendation would be a custom function that:

- loops over an input array
- applies the logic you outlined
- return the condensed array

Given your specific requirements isn't a single, magical PHP function that does this. Yet, there are dozens of [PHP array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) you could utilize within your custom function.

If you need help on a particular piece, update your post or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function with a callback that handles your specific requirements for addition and uniqueness.