# Combine value of multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, combiners

I have multidimensional Array output like this As below in which

i want to Combine the values of `pid` and `map` using any separator but not `comma(,)` where `id` is same

This is a sample data Array has more than 20000 values and depth level unknown may be 18 or 20

```
 Array
(
[pid] => 10000
[map] => 11, 11
[id] => 5740
[parentId] => 5739
[text] => Text1
[children] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [pid] => 600
        [map] => 
        [id] => 5741
        [parentId] => 5740
        [text] => Adv
        [children] => Array
         (
            [0] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 620
                [map] => 115.43271636963, 28
                [id] => 5745
                [parentId] => 5741
                [text] => Text1.1
              )
            [1] => Array
              (
                [pid] => 621
                [map] => 1, 2
                [id] => 5745
                [parentId] => 5741
                [text] => Text1.1
              )
            [2] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 1748
                [map] => 11.43, 28
                [id] => 5746
                [parentId] => 5741
                [text] => Text1.2
             ) 
          )
      )
    [1] => Array
     (
        [pid] => 700
        [map] => 15, 17
        [id] => 5750
        [parentId] => 5740
        [text] => Text2
        [children] => Array
         (
            [0] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 500
                [map] => 139.525390625, 35.797920227051
                [id] => 5751
                [parentId] => 5750
                [text] => Text2.1
              )
            [1] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 502
                [map] => 15, 17
                [id] => 5751
                [parentId] => 5750
                [text] => Text2.1
              )
            [2] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 1157
                [map] => 7.8320698738098, 48.023639678955
                [id] => 5754
                [parentId] => 5750
                [text] => Text2.2
             )
         )    
     )
  )
)
```

Expected output is. Here i am using `:` as separator

```
 Array
(
[pid] => 10000
[map] => 11, 11
[id] => 5740
[parentId] => 5739
[text] => Text1
[children] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [pid] => 600
        [map] => 
        [id] => 5741
        [parentId] => 5740
        [text] => Adv
        [children] => Array
         (
            [0] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 620 : 621
                [map] => 115.43271636963, 28 : 1, 2
                [id] => 5745
                [parentId] => 5741
                [text] => Text1.1
              )
            [1] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 1748
                [map] => 11.43, 28
                [id] => 5746
                [parentId] => 5741
                [text] => Text1.2
             ) 
          )
      )
    [1] => Array
     (
        [pid] => 700
        [map] => 15, 17
        [id] => 5750
        [parentId] => 5740
        [text] => Text2
        [children] => Array
         (
            [0] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 500 : 502
                [map] => 139.525390625, 35.797920227051 : 15, 17
                [id] => 5751
                [parentId] => 5750
                [text] => Text2.1
              )
            [1] => Array
             (
                [pid] => 1157
                [map] => 7.8320698738098, 48.023639678955
                [id] => 5754
                [parentId] => 5750
                [text] => Text2.2
             )
         )    
     )
  )
)
```

I Have tried many code

one of them function is `array_merge_recursive`

Also

```
function super_unique($array)
{
  $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

  foreach ($result as $key => $value)
  {
    if ( is_array($value) )
    {
      $result[$key] = super_unique($value);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Also i have tried from this solutions [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541901/combining-multidimensional-array-values-in-php)

Thanks in advance let me know if there is any function

Comment: So, you only want to merge items that don't have `children` array element?

Comment: @Ja͢ck i want to merge on same level i dont want to destroy structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no one function that can do this for you. The approach I took is:

1. Determine the level at which to merge, which is when there's no `'children'` key in the current array item; in this case, we must perform a recursive step to examine the deeper child elements.
2. Iterate through the child elements and perform another recursive step if it contains a `'children'` key.
3. Build a temporary array that keeps all possible values for each key in the child elements and remove those elements from the main array.
4. Rebuild the main array with elements from the temporary array.

The code:

```
function recursive_group(array &$arr)
{
    if (array_key_exists('children', $arr)) {
        // 1. perform recursive step
        recursive_group($arr['children']);
        return;
    }

    $groups = [];
    foreach ($arr as $key => &$subarr) {
        if (array_key_exists('children', $subarr)) {
            // 2. perform another recursive step
            recursive_group($subarr['children']);
        } elseif (isset($subarr['id'])) {
            // 3. build temporary array
            $id = $subarr['id'];
            foreach ($subarr as $param_name => $param_value) {
                if ($param_name != 'id') {
                    $groups[$id][$param_name][] = $param_value;
                }
            }
            // 3. remove from main array
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }

    if ($groups) {
        // 4. rebuild main array
        foreach ($groups as $id => $params) {
            $tmp = ['id' => $id];
            foreach ($params as $param_name => $param_values) {
                $tmp[$param_name] = join(' : ', $param_values);
            }
            $arr[] = $tmp;
        }
    }
}
```